# unix update file into an executable jar file not working

Tags: unix, jar, zip, updates

I have an issue with my jar, it's an executable jar (with springboot).
My jar is build/package with maven and everything work fine. I could run it, it work like it should.
The issue is when I want to update one of the file into the jar, before trying to update, if I run "jar tvf myjar.jar" or "unzip -l myjar.jar" I could see my jar content with all the files. Then I do the file update :

```
jar -uf myjar.jar the/path/where/my/file/is/myfile
```

I double check, the jar and the file have correct right, the path to the file is the same as the one in the jar but instead of update "myfile" into the correct path in the jar, it delete all the jar content, and all I have at the end is a jar with just one file under the path : "the/path/where/my/file/is/myfile"

I try to so the update using zip command, but I have the following error :

```
 zip -u myjar.jar the/path/where/my/file/is/myfile
    zip warning: expected 300 entries but found 57
 zip error: Zip file structure invalid (myjar.jar)
```

I try to do the same action on my windows computer, using 7z command line :

```
7z u myjar.jar the/path/where/my/file/is/myfile
```

and everything work fine.

I need to do this action on a centos linux system on command line only inside a shell script to make my jar deployment fully automatic, so I could not download it on my windows computer each time to make the file update.

Edit :
The jar is create with maven, it contains my application back (java/springboot) and my front (angular)
I have follow this page to build it : https://marco.dev/deploy-java-angular-one
I use this plugin to make it executable :

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
         <executable>true</executable>
         <mainClass>com.my.app.Application</mainClass>
     </configuration>
     <executions> 
         <execution> 
            <goals> 
                <goal>repackage</goal> 
            </goals> 
         </execution> 
      </executions> 
 </plugin>
```

Any ideas why the jar update command line erase all my jar content instead of updating my file ?
Is there any other specific command/argument to use with executable jar ?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us how exactly you created `myjar.jar`.

Comment: I add more information about the jar creation in thequestion

Comment: Do you create the jar on the same system where you encounter the problem?

Comment: Hello, I have the problem with jar build on my computer (windows 10) or on gitlab (linux centos runner)